# Implementing Cormen's Algorithms for MergeSort with Generics, how should I initialize the 'sentinel' value?

Tags: java, generics, recursion, mergesort

Here is my code so far, I have the code where an Integer value is being sent to a T[] array as a placeholder, I know it will cause a compilation error. For reference I attached an image of the psuedocode so you know what I am trying to achieve in my code out of Cormen: [Psuedocode of Cormen's Merge Sort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RdzQ.jpg)

```
/**
 * Sorter
 */
public class Sorter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] arr = { 3, 7, 5, 9, 11 };
        sort(arr);
    }

    static <T extends Comparable<T>> void sort(T[] items) {
        mergeSort((T[]) items, 0, items.length - 1);
    }

    static <T extends Comparable<T>> void mergeSort(T[] A, int p, int r) { // should use int or Integer?
        int q;
        if (p < r) {
            q = Math.floorDiv((p + r), 2);
            mergeSort(A, p, q);
            mergeSort(A, (q + 1), r);
            merge(A, p, q, r);
        }
    }

    private static <T extends Comparable<T>> void merge(T[] A, int p, int q, int r) {
        int n = q - p + 1;
        int m = r - q;

        T[] L = (T[]) new Comparable[n + 1];
        T[] R = (T[]) new Comparable[m + 1];
        int i, j;

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            L[i] = A[p + i];

        }

        for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            R[j] = A[q + j + 1];
        }

        L[n] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
//sentinel value(s)
        L[m] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        i = 0;
        j = 0;
        int k;

        for (k = p; k <= r; k++) {
            if (L[i].compareTo(R[j]) <= 0) {
                A[k] = L[i];
                i++;
            } else {
                A[k] = R[j];
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only possible value that can be assigned to arbitrary reference types is `null`. It's possible to use `null` as your sentinel value, but you'll also need to change your comparison logic to avoid a `NullPointerException`:

```
private static <T extends Comparable<T>> int nullSafeCompare(T o1, T o2) {
    if  (o1 == null) {
        if (o2 == null) return 0;
        else return 1;
    }
    if (o2 == null) return -1;
    return o1.compareTo(o2);
}
```

Called like this:

```
if (nullSafeCompare(L[i], R[j]) <= 0) {
```

Note that there is an additional logic error in the original code (that I'll leave to you to find) that produces incorrect results (even if everything is changed to `int[]`). Look for off-by-one errors.

Comment: null can't be used as a sentinel value in the normal sense of the term. If the code has to check for null, it  will end up being the same overhead as checking for index at the end of a run.